# Getting existing Internet Explorer Window Created by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I need to interact with a IE window that was previously created in PowerShell without using a global variable.

```
If(WindowAlreadyCreatedByPowerShell){
    $IE = WindowAlreadyCreatedByPowerShell
}Else{
    $IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
    $IE.visible = $true; 
    $IE.navigate($url);
}
```

Note: Using `((New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows).Invoke() | ?{$_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer"}` returns nothing

Comment: You mean you want to get the window that was created without specifying the var in the parent scope?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with but the easiest way would be to place `$IE` in the parent scope. I know you can get the `HWND` from the `$IE` ComObject but to get an object based on the `HWND`, you may need to `P/Invoke` into the win32 API, and I'm not sure it's possible to get an `$IE` ComObject from an existing `HWND` handle.

Comment: I'm also curious why you are avoiding declaring `$IE` in the parent scope.

Comment: Figured out a solution that doesn't require `P/Invoke` and still uses the window handle to find the correct window. But this is still a lot of work for avoiding the use of a variable in the parent scope, since you are effectively throwing away the object assignment only to figure out which object it was later.

Comment: If you just want to connect to a running instance of Internet Explorer you could also call `[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('InternetExplorer.Application')`

Answer (score 2):

So you will need to store **something** in the parent scope - if you don't want to store the IE object, store the URL you opened, or even better, the window handle (`HWND` property, which should be unique). Otherwise, you won't have a reliable way of getting which window you want, especially if your session is opening *other* IE windows as well.

```
# Variable for the created IE window handle
$expectedHWND = $null

# This will enumerate all ShellWindows opened as a COM object in your session
$allShellWindows = ( New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application ).Windows()

# Get the IE object matching the HWND you stored off when you first opened IE
# If you opened other windows in the session, the HWND should be unique so you
# can get the correct window you are expecting
$existingIE = $allShellWindows | Where-Object {
  $_.HWND -eq $expectedHWND
}

# Your code, slightly modified
if( $existingIE ){
  # You should be able to operate on $existingIE here instead of reassigning it to $IE
  Write-Output "Found existing IE session: HWND - $($existingIE.HWND), URL - $($existingIE.LocationURL)"
} else {
  $IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
  $IE.visible = $true; 
  $IE.navigate($url);
  $expectedHWND = $IE.HWND
}
```

If you run that twice, but don't set `$expectedHWND` to `$null` the second time, it will find your IE window. Note that this is a lot of work for avoiding storing a variable in the parent scope, but is technically feasible.

You will likely need to curate the sample above for your specific application, but serves as a good demonstration of getting an operable object for the IE window you previously opened.